# How to pass event from ViewCell to parent object, where ListView is placed

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, xamarin.forms

I want to handle the events from the cell within the parent object. This is the XAML of the parent object:

```xml
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Views.SomeView"
             xmlns:customViews="clr-namespace:App.Views;assembly=App"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

  <ListView x:Name="MyList"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <customViews:CustomListItem/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

As you can see I have a custom cell defined in my data template. The cell itselfs looks something like this:

```xml
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="App.Views.CustomListItem">

    <Image x:Name="infoButton" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</ViewCell>
```

In the code behind file I add a tap recognizer to the image:

```cs
public partial class CustomListItem : ViewCell
{
    private TapGestureRecognizer onIconTapppedRecognizer;

    public CustomListItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Make it tapable
        this.onIconTapppedRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        this.onIconTapppedRecognizer.Tapped += Icon_Tapped;
        this.infoButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(this.onIconTapppedRecognizer);
    }

    private async void Icon_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await MainPage.Instance.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage(this.viewModel));
    }
}
```

Now I want to receive the `Icon_Tapped` event on `SomeView`. [This approach](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/handling-child-control-event-in-listview-using-xamarinforms1) doesn't work, because the cell is defined in a separate object and not on the same "page". [Another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25983987/426227) requires to pass the view model in the code via constructor, but I have defined that in XAML. Furthermore, I have a model for each entry in the list view and not one for the whole list view.

How can I receive the event from the cell?

Comment: Why not just add an event to `CustomListItem` and handle it in `SomeView`?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to avoid binding back to the ViewModel of `SomeView`?  You could add the GestureRecognizer in the `ListItem` XAML and bind it back to a Command in the BindingContext of the parent (i.e. the ListView's source, or it's parent ViewModel).

Comment: @icebat: Where should I subscribe/unscubscribe from that event? The cell is initialized in the `DataTemplate` in XAML.

Comment: @ctacke: It's a mixture of MVVM and no MVVM I think ... I saw [this code](https://github.com/stvansolano/crossPlatformDevelopment/blob/master/FeaturedApps/ToDoApp/CrossPlatformApp/CrossPlatformApp/Views/ToDoItemCell.xaml.cs). Is this what you mean? How do I bind it back than?

Comment: With your layout nothing is stopping you from subscribing right in XAML. If you plan to extract DataTemplate to reuse it, you can make routed event instead and catch it at ListView level. It's nothing complicated.

Comment: @icebat: I could put my complete `ViewCell` layout into `DataTemplate`, but the real layout is much more complex and I also have some code in the code behind file. I would like to have this separated to have things clearer. How do you route the event to the `ListView` level?

Comment: Where would you handle `Tapped` event if you could subscribe to it directly? It's the same. But, it's your personal preference. You can check routed events on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview), it's very useful to know when working with WPF (and related) in any case.

Comment: @icebat: I would like to handle the `Icon_Tapped` event on `SomeView` (parent object consisting out of `StackLayout` at the main level). What I noticed is, that if I supply the name of the event on `ViewCell` level, the event has to be on `ViewCell` level. Otherwise the app crashes. Thanks, I'll have a look into this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't know that you can define custom events on any object:

`SomeView` XAML now looks like this

```xml
<customViews:CustomListItem ButtonClicked="SomeView_ButtonClicked"/>
```

The according event handler in the code behind file from `SomeView`

```cs
private async void SomeView_ButtonClicked(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

On my `ViewCell` `CustomListItem` I have defined a public event handler like this

```cs
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> ButtonClicked;
```

And from the event handler from my added gesture recognizer, this event is invoked:

```
private void Icon_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ButtonClicked?.Invoke(sender, new CustomEventArgs(this.model));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! How do you get a reference to the viewmodel (`this.model`) in your CustomListItem class?

Comment: What I ended up doing:  passed a reference to my viewmodel like this: `this.ButtonClicked?.Invoke(sender, BindingContext as MyAwesomeViewModel);`

Comment: @JannieTheunissen: Glad you figured it out by yourself. In `OnBindingContextChanged()` I do this `var viewModel = BindingContext as MyAwesomeViewModel;` which is basically the same.